# What fungus is this, and how to get rid of it?

Tags: identification, weed-control, fungus

Next to our lawn, we have a strip of bark-covered earth where we grow blackberries and raspberries. Some fungus recently appeared on that bark.

Yesterday it looked like a handful of wet yellow cereal strewn about. Today (after immense rain) it looks like a spongy carpet, and it's no longer yellow but rather salmon-colored.

What is it, and much more important: how do I get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just one of the slime moulds, and its there in association with your bark chips - it does get bigger and changes form if the weather has been wet, it likes lots of wet, its getting ready to produce spores. It'll disappear on its own over time, more quickly if it dries out, but if you don't like the look of it, remove the bark chips its growing on. It won't harm your plants, but does look rather unpleasant. More reading here about slime moulds generally

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_mold

Answer (score 2):

It's called (inappropriately) [Dog Vomit Slime Mold or Dog Vomit Fungus](http://www.hsu.edu/Academics/ARNatureTrivia/Misc-blob.html), but it goes by other (more savory?) names as well (sometimes it is identified as scrambled egg slime when it is fresh/yellow). *[Fuligo septica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuligo_septica)* is not really harmful, but has been proven to cause asthmatic issues. It starts out as bright yellow (for about 24 hours) before turning the color in the photo. As it ages it might begin to ooze or turn black or develop a crust.

It's relatively resistant to copper and silver based fungicides, and currently, there are no known (good) methods for controlling it, but some advice can be found here: [Identifying and Controlling Dog Vomit Fungus](http://organicgardening.about.com/od/diseases/a/Identifying-And-Controlling-Dog-Vomit-Fungus.htm). It is known to be carried by beetles and it is very common on mulch (showing up a few weeks after adding fresh mulch).

After about a week, it finally results in a brown pile of spore. For some more pictures and information see this: [Dog Vomit Fungus Pictures and Information](http://www.personal.psu.edu/sam21/dogvomit.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I am to sure what this is. But I do know what would be best to get ride of it. I would simply get that stuff in a bag or something and get the stuff away from your plants. If it is removed it can not grow in that are no more the way I look at it. And once you have gotten all of the chips taken that have that stuff on it then put down more chips. If this keeps happening I would be wondering if this is coming directly from the chips. If this ends up happening then get all of those chips out and place different chips.